# Push an new object in an existing object in a loop

Tags: javascript, object

I'm looping through some JSON and am trying to push a new object in an existing 'master' object on each iteration. Basically, I'm looking for a push method to push objects into objects instead of pushing them in an array.

This will only push one object in the local object.

```
var local = {};
for (let i = 0; i < data[2].length; i++) {
            let friend = {};
            friend.name = data[2].users[i][0].name;
            friend.screenName =  data[2].users[i][0].name;
            friend.avatar =  data[2].users[i][0].name;

             local["friend"] = friend;
        };
```

Ideally, I want the final local object to look something like:

```
{ friend: 
   { name: '123',
     screenName: '123',
     avatar: '123' },
   { name: '123',
     screenName: '123',
     avatar: '123' },
   { name: '123',
     screenName: '123',
     avatar: '123' },   
   { name: '123',
     screenName: '123',
     avatar: '123' } }
```

Comment: Friend needs to be an array. `friend: [{name: ...},{name: ...}]`

Comment: your structure is not valid. do you need an array of objects? or an object with named properties?

Comment: its overriding the values with same key `friend` all time

Comment: You could write `var local = {friends: []};` and later on call `local.friends.push(friend);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use an array of friends:

```
var local = {
 friends:[]//an array of friends
};
for (let i = 0; i < data[2].length; i++) {
            let friend = {};
            friend.name = data[2].users[i][0].name;
            friend.screenName =  data[2].users[i][0].name;
            friend.avatar =  data[2].users[i][0].name;
            local.friends.push(friend);
 };
```

or maybe easier using map:

```
var local={
  friends:data[2].users.map(el=>({
    name:el.name,
    screenName:el.name,
    avatar:el.name
  }))
};
```

---

So this structure emerges as result:

```
 {
   friends: [
     { name: '123',
       screenName: '123',
       avatar: '123' },
    { name: '123',
      screenName: '123',
      avatar: '123' },
    { name: '123',
      screenName: '123',
      avatar: '123' },   
   { name: '123',
     screenName: '123',
     avatar: '123' }
 ] 
}
```

Comment: Why not initialize `friend` in the first line and access it by `local.friend`? By the way, calling it `friends` instead of `friend` would make more sense.

Comment: Usually my edit would be another answer, but as being a social democrat ... ;)

Comment: Thank you for your generosity!